# Leaflet Cluster Number as Variable

Tags: r, leaflet, leaflet-r

I'm looking to make a map using Leaflet in R, where the clusters shows the sum of a variable associated with the markers, instead of the number of markers in the area.

For example:
If there are 4 markers in a cluster.
Each marker has a number of dollars associated with that location:
Point 1: 10
Point 2: 15
Point 3: 15
Point 4: 1

The cluster should read 41 instead of 4. Is there a way to do this in leaflet?

Also I have too many data points and dollar amounts to break each point down into 1 voucher for each dollar.

Comment: Are you referring to the [Marker Cluster Plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) ? Or are you referring to points that are clustered in space by some criteria?

Comment: Cluster Marker plug in:

leaflet(Waitlist_gc) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(
  clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
  label=~as.character(Map)

Comment: Something similar to this but translatable into R:
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/363

Comment: Does this help ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53245984/leaflet-r-how-to-make-appearance-of-clustered-icon-related-to-statistics-of-the
(If not please update/edit your q with your code and what isn't working / what would be expected)

Comment: That's the exact code I was looking for, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53245984/leaflet-r-how-to-make-appearance-of-clustered-icon-related-to-statistics-of-the

Comment: @Spacedman agreed, surprised there isn't a way to mark as a duplicate of a different SO network